# Windows API hook, custom save as file dialog to save directly to webserver via POST

Tags: winapi, hook, save-as

I want to write a custom save as dialog that is hooked into the File -> "Save As" of most Windows program. This custom dialog will allow the user to enter their username, password, destination folder and uploads the file to the web server via a POST. If the user clicks cancel, it will call the original file dialog.

I've been reading up about Windows API hooking and this is vaguely how I think I would approach this:

1. Intercept "Save As"
2. Display my custom dialog, return some temporary path on the drive
3. Let the program write file to the temporary path, assume it calls WINAPI CreateFile(...) for now
4. Read the temporary file and upload to web server
5. Clean up temporary file

But I still can't get my head around the steps required to pull this off. Assuming I can intercept the "Save As" and CreateFile function, how do I detect the CreateFile was called from a "Save As" and not just any random file creation? I can think of a hack where I keep track of the time difference of when the File dialog got open and CreateFile got called.

My alternative solution is to use the existing file dialog and create a special folder on the disk, that is constantly monitored. When a file gets written there it will call an external program that uploads the file. I haven't looked into how to do this yet. I suspect this is easier.

**UPDATE**

As a first baby step, I wrote a .NET task tray application that allows the user to enter their login details and a folder to monitor. Whenever a file gets dropped in there there it will upload to the web server. So far it seems to work. Now I just need to figure out how to add a nice shortcut to the left pane of the file dialog. Once that's done I think I got a solution I'm happy with.

Comment: Be very careful about applications that don't immediately use the file name. A perfectly legitimate use is to prompt for a file name for use later on, maybe months or years in the future or even repeatedly.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to hook or patch anything. Create a shell namespace extension that supports `IStorage::CreateStream` and implements it by returning a stream that POSTs its data to the Web server. The user can then choose to save the file to your namespace extension in order to upload the file.

Comment: I like the sound of this solution already. Going to read up on it now.

Comment: However, creating a custom Shell Namespace Extension is not a trivial task itself, let alone implementing the `IStorage` interface for it.  On the other hand, creating a SNE would be a good idea because it also integrates with Windows Explorer, so users would be able to drag&drop files directly onto your SNE and you would be able to POST those files to your WebServer as well.

Comment: Does anyone know of any software that implements the suggestion from Raymond Chen?

Answer (score 1):

Hooking the standard save dialog requires you to inject a DLL into every running process and have it replace the import stub of the the Win32 API `GetSaveFileName()` function in the process's PE header (something anti-virus and anti-malware apps are not likely to be happy about).

Then there is the new-style save dialog that was introduced in Vista using the new `IFileSaveDialog` COM interface instead of `GetSaveFileName()`.  For that, you would have to uninstall and replace Microsoft's default FileDialog COM object with a custom implementation.

That does not count custom-made save dialogs, which you are not likely to hook.

If, by some miracle, you can hook the dialog and have it return a custom path of your own creation, you don't need to hook `CreateFile()` itself,  Just monitor the folder that you create for your purposes.  Place it where it is unlikely that any other app (or user) besides you will write files to.  You can create a custom subfolder in the user's or system'ss `AppData` folder for that purpose.  You can use `SHGetSpecialFolderPath()` and/or `SHGetKnownFolderPath()` to find those folders.

The tricky part will be detecting when the file is finished being written to and has been closed.  You will have to monitor the folder for changes, such as with `ReadDirectoryChangesW()` or `SHChangeNotifyRegister()`, and periodically open new/modified files for exclusive access.  If a file is still open by someone else, you won't be able to open it yourself.  But once you do open it, you can do whatever you want with it.

Comment: Thanks for that. I had a feeling the hook solution wasn't go to be very nice. But thanks for the heads up on the API to do folder monitoring. I'm new to all this so any help is much appreciated.